# in python, I want to select from array an range by given string

Tags: python, arrays, filter

is there any method or external library that receives some range as string and converts it to the index in the array?

I mean something like the print selected pages function in google chrome - [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1379552?hl=en)

so then it will select the related items from the array?

example:

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']

x.get_selected_items('1, 3-4, 6')

>>>['a','c','d','f']
```

Thanks

Comment: Just parse the string yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shove your text range through [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577279-generate-list-of-numbers-from-hyphenated-and-comma/), then pass it to [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), and finally apply it to your sequence. Note the off-by-one bit, so either map each element to subtract 1, or put a dummy element at the beginning of your sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> items = itemgetter(0, slice(2, 4), 5)(x)
>>> [j for i in items for j in (i if isinstance(i, list) else [i])]
['a', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```

Comment: **+1** - I had no idea itemgetter was this powerful!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
y = x[:1] + x[2:4] + x[5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> x = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> sum(itemgetter(slice(0, 1), slice(2, 4), slice(5, 6))(x), [])
['a', 'c', 'd', 'f']
```